# n-Chlorobutane addition to benzene by Friedel-Crafts mechanism

Tags: organic-chemistry

I recently had an exam question, pictured below, regarding a Friedel-Crafts alkylation of benzene. The question wants to know what would form as the major product. I responded that the second option, sec-butylbenzene, would form as the major product. This response was marked incorrect. I discussed the item with the professor, who told me that the correct answer (last option) was that "more than one of these products" would form.

I located a textbook example, also pictured below, which lists the sec-butyl product as the major (49% yield), and the n-butylbenzene as the minor (29% yield). This sums to 78% of the yield. I wholly agree that more products will form, but I see no evidence to suggest that they could be considered a majority product.

I have searched Reaxys and ACS for clarifying literature, but have not found anything helpful. Is anyone aware of literature which would offer experimental data to support either position, or perhaps another way that I should be thinking about this reaction?

[image: Test question]

[image: Textbook example]

Comment: It’s not clear to me what your selected answer was and what answer the instructor considered correct.

Comment: My selected answer was the sec-butyl option, the one with the filled in dot. The professor said that the last option, "More than one of these products" was correct.

Comment: It says major product in the question, so I’d agree with the rearranged sec-butyl option. 

(I would say that this seems less about the chemistry, which you seem to understand just fine, and more about the semantics of how the question is worded)

Comment: It says "major product ***(s)***", which kinda hints at a possibility that multiple products can all be considered major at once. If not for that detail, I'd say that sec-butyl is the only correct answer.

Comment: Even though butylbenzene is considered minor in this case, would it be fair to say that it is a secondary major product when taking the other miscellaneous products into account? That is the only other way I can rationalize the answer

Comment: If you deleted out the "major product(s)" part of the question, what would people answer?